# Razor not render my data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Following code will never be render on my page (`ViewData["ERRORS"]` is not empty), I don't know why...

```html
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.saveButton').click(function () {
                $('#frmMain').submit();
            });

            @if (ViewData["ERRORS"] != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in (Dictionary<string,string>)ViewData["ERRORS"])
                {
                    <text>$("#@item.Key").addClass("has-error");$("#__count_@item.Key").val("@item.Value");</text>
                }
            }

        });
    </script>
}
```

the Controller Code where `ViewData` is generated:

```cs
     Dictionary<string, string> errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();

     #region electric
     if(form["__count_ht__"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(form["__count_ht__"]))
     {
         float.TryParse(form["__count_ht__"], out ht);
         if(ht <= 0)
         {
             errors.Add("ht", form["__count_ht__"]);
         }
     }
     if (form["__count_nt__"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(form["__count_nt__"]))
     {
         float.TryParse(form["__count_nt__"], out nt);
         if(nt <= 0)
         {
             errors.Add("nt", form["__count_nt__"]);
         }
     }
     #endregion

     if(errors.Count == 0)
     {

     }else
     {
         ViewData["ERRORS"] = errors;
     }

     return View();
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Please show code where you initialize `ViewData["ERRORS"]`

Comment: Are you sure, that it is not rendered in your html? You renders <text> tags inside of <script> tag, and it looks strange.

Comment: As long as you have a `ViewData["ERRORS"] = someDictionary;` statement in the controller action that rendered this view, your code should work fine. It is also possible that you are not seeing any output generated if the dictionary passed to the ViewData is empty. Could you show the controller action that rendered this view and which is supposed to populate the ViewData value?

Comment: does the scripts section get rendered?

Comment: Yes scripts section was render. If I set a breakpoint to the foreach the code halt and I can show the data.

Comment: Could you please show in your question the rendered HTML of the relevant script section as seen in the browser?

Comment: i see following in browser code

    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.saveButton').click(function () {
                $('#frmMain').submit();
            });


        });
    </script>

Comment: okay, so it looks like `ViewData["ERRORS"]` is not populated or it is an empty dictionary. It will be hard to help you any further if you don't show the relevant section of the controller action that is supposed to populate this value.

Comment: the Controller Code is on top

Comment: The only explanation I can find is that the code doesn't enter the `else` condition where you populate the `ViewData["ERRORS"]` when rendering the view.

Comment: yes the viewdata is not empty :( but thanks for help. I not understand this error ;(

Comment: which version of asp.net mvc are you using?

Comment: It seems to me you are throwing away the model binder and doing its work by hand in your controller. All that controller code is redundant, you need to define a model with validation attributes and only check `ModelState.IsValid` in the controller.

Comment: <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: the problem got solved.

It was very simple. I'm using @html.actionlink to submit my form, but i have forget onclick="return false" on it.

Thanks for help :)